# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/filename.html.php on line 1834

Tags: php

I am getting an error message when trying to load a page on my site;

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/filename.html.php on line 1834.

Looking at my code, it looks correct.  I cannot find any missing brackets or extra characters.

```
<?php
} 
else
{ ?>
    <div class="componentheading"><?php echo JText::_('Purchase New Subscription')?></div>
        <div class="contentpanopen">
            <p><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_jcs&view=jcs&layout=history&Itemid=$Itemid")?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('Subscriptions History')?></a></p>
            <p> No subscription Plans have been assigned to you, to to know more about our subscription plans please contact us at <a href="mailto:Renoferri@gmail.com">Renoferri@gmail.com</a> </p>
   <?php
}

}
```

Line 1834 is the line with just the word "else" on it.

This code immediately follows a  javascript.

If I remove the line, or this code, I get other errors.  I think maybe something is not being escaped, but no matter what I try, I cannot get the dang error fixed.

Any ideas to try anyone?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: "If I remove the line, or this code, I get other errors... no matter what I try, I cannot get the dang error fixed." Strange. Randomly adding and removing lines usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have one two many curly braces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What comes before this code? You open the code snippet with a `}`... is there another else clause about it?

```
if (..) {
} else {
} else {
   .... your snippet here
}
```

would be one way for that error to occur. An IF() statement can have only one "else" clause, unless it's an "else if".